# Open a doc file with Office 365 API AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, office365

I have an AngularJS single page Web app. I have a server that stores documents like .doc, .docx, etc. What I want to do is downloading these documents (this, I can do) and hand them somehow to Office 365, then open it for editing inside(!) my webapp. Like, in a div element or something like that.

Is there any way to achive this or something similar? Basicly my goal is to be able to edit Office documents inside my app with Office 365 environment.

I appriciate any help and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now it is not possible to embed a document from Office 365 for editing in a website.

The only thing that is possible is to embed it for viewing, with the Office Online apps.

You can do this with the Graph API, and some small hacks to get the right source for the iframe with the embedded file.

Answer (score 4):

Just to have the full story. I've done my own research about this. There are more options to do this, actually.

First of all, if you want to open it as quick as possible without user authentication, then you need a publicly accessible link for your document. Then you can put in an iframe and open the document as written [here](https://blogs.office.com/2013/04/10/office-web-viewer-view-office-documents-in-a-browser/).

**Make sure that the document link is URL encoded in the src of the iframe, and also make sure that your document is available throught the default http port, the 80 port! I wasted 2 days because I had a link that was hosted on the 8088 port, and it just couldn't handle it. If somebody from Microsoft reads it, then hereby, I want to express how annoying it is, and that I couldn't find any documentation about this.**

Your second option is if you upload the document through the Microsoft Graph API (I recommend to use the unified API). In this case you have to deal with user authentication as well. Or you have to wait until microsoft will be done with the service to service API call, support. Because up until now, it isn't supporting file operations.

If you choose this solution, then a little info about opening the document. For the src, you can find the base if you create a new document in Office 365, then go File / Share / Embed. Then, there will be an iframe for you to embed the document. If you change the sourcedoc paramater to the eTAG (but I suppose id would be good as well) of the item you want to open, then it should open the document. You can use the same link for word, excel, and powerpoint as well, but don't forget that Office 365 can't open pdf files or images. You have to find other solutions for that. (Like object for pdf (be careful with this, because edge doesn't support dynamic data for object), and img for images). From here, you can put a button somewhere on the UI for the user to open the document in Office 365, so he/she will be able to edit it, then after he/she is done you can sync it back to your server and maybe delete, the file from office 365.
**I really reccomend you to do this on server side, because otherwise it will be slow in weaker devices.**

You can find the documentation for the Microsoft (unified) Graph API [here](http://graph.microsoft.io/)

Comment: do you have a new solution in 2018?